# Text in front of looped video

Tags: html, css

I have a looped video with this css code

```
.bg video{
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 91.4%;
object-fit: cover;
```

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="bg">
        <video src="videos/S22-Ultra-unboxing.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
        <p>New S22 Ultra</p>
</div>
```

I want to have the "New S22 Ultra" in front of the video.
And always when I try, the text is all the way in the top right corner. If you don't understand what I mean I can always send you the whole file.

Comment: Why are you absolute positioning the video element? It seems like you can achieve what you want relative positioning the parent `.bg` and absolute positioning the `p` element within the parent. Let the browser position the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make your `.bg` set to `position: relative;` in order to
- place your `<p>` text with elevated `z-index: 1;` and `position: absolute`
- Set `top` and `right` properties for your `<p>` text as desired.
- Would be simpler for you to place that `<p>` inside a `<div>` instead

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  height: 80vh;
}

.bg-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.bg-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; /* not necessary if order in HTML is appropriate */
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <video class="bg-video" src="https://r.myxotod.de/codepen.io/ambilight/sports.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
  <div class="bg-text">New S22 Ultra</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I set just .bg to poition: relative;
then is the whole video like 1 cm high

Comment: @Tomaatje07 sorry to hear. See the example above.